# How can I target an alias column name in the where clause when a same column name exists?

Tags: sql, sqlite, alias

So in the original table `SELECT id FROM drivers` there is a column `teamid`. However in my complicated query this `teamid` is not used for the output.

I am using a `teamid` but from another table as an alias.

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    (
        SELECT
            teamid
        FROM
            attendancelist
        WHERE
            activityid = 3
            AND driverid = driver.id
    ) as teamid
FROM
    drivers
```

When I try to use a WHERE-clause on `teamid`. It uses the `teamid` from `driver` and not the alias `teamid`. The only way I found to avoid this, is by renaming the alias to a column name not on the driver table, such as: `customteamid`.

But I was wondering, just like you can explicitly get `teamid` from `driver` with `driver.teamid`. Is there a way you can explicitly get the alias column name?

Comment: You can't, the WHERE clause is evaluated _before_ the subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference sub-query from `SELECT` clause in `WHERE`.

To do what you described you should use `JOIN` instead.
Something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    attendancelist.teamid
FROM
    drivers
    inner join attendancelist on (
        attendancelist.activityid = 3
        AND attendancelist.driverid = drivers.id
    )
where
    attendancelist.teamid = 100500 -- YOU CONDITION HERE
```

EDIT: if your request assumes `teamid` being `NULL` as a valid result, and you plan to use `attendancelist.teamid` in some elaborate way inside your `WHERE` clause - use `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    attendancelist.teamid
FROM
    drivers
    left join attendancelist on (
        attendancelist.activityid = 3
        AND attendancelist.driverid = drivers.id
    )
where
    (colA + attendancelist.teamid = colB) 
 OR (colC = colD)
```

Comment: The LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result here. Perhaps that's what OP wants? Anyway, either do an INNER JOIN, or move the teamid condition to the ON clause.

Comment: @jarlh, since it was not clear how OP wanted to use `teamid` in his clause, I decided to use `LEFT JOIN`: not to drop rows where `teamid` is not found. Also, my `WHERE` is just an example. If OP will use it in some elaborate way (like `columnA in (1,2,attendancelist.teamid)` or `colA + attendancelist.teamid = colB OR colC = colD`) it could be useful.

Comment: I agree the question is unclear, but your query is doing a LEFT JOIN that returns INNER JOIN result - which is somewhat contradictory.

Comment: @jarlh, agree: edited answer.